# Can Block Device IDs in LVM be set statically?

Tags: lvm, snapshot, block-device

I have a system using LVM2 with a single PV which contains 1 VG which in-turn contains 5 logical volumes (`/`, `/home`, `/var`, `/swap`, `/data`).

When I create a snapshot of LV `/` (`lvcreate -L 15G -s -n root_snap_test01 /dev/vg01/lv_root`), upon reboot the device id (using something like `stat /home`) will show that it's device id has been incremented for each snapshot of `/` that is created.  Further, if `/` is restored (`lvconvert --merge ...`) from a snapshot, `/home`'s device id will become `/`'s original device id.

Is there a way to specify the Block Device (and assuming resulting device id that is output as part of the stat command) for a given set of Logical Volumes?

Is this something that could be applied statically given a LV Name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device from coreutils' stat is the major and minor device numbers. This is a lower level identifier than most storage administration tools deal with. I do not think it can be provided by the user, nor is it static.

An identifier that stays with the data is file system UUID. For XFS, set one with `xfs_admin -U generate`  When taking snapshots, the UUID is duplicated, but can be re-generated or set, for example:  `xfs_admin -U 195d1175-1231-4773-834e-d738bf665bea`

Also, LVM maintains named symlinks.  `/dev/vg01/lv_root` is a link to a device mapper special file, representing the major and minor for the kernel.